# How bind the data in grid view based on conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have fallowing dataset

```
ActualMachineId BlockScheduleVersionId  ActualStartDate ActivityId  BlockScheduleActivityId BLOCKNO 

UT13-PM-4   UT2-BSV-14  13/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-2   2284    
UT13-PM-4   UT2-BSV-6   08/06/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-3   6396    
UT13-PM-5   UT2-BSV-5   12/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-4   1239    
UT13-PM-5   UT2-BSV-7   12/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-5   2277    
UT13-PM-4   UT2-BSV-8   08/06/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-6   1239    
UT13-PM-3   UT2-BSV-9   21/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-8   2283
```

If I bind the data I will get all  repeated records also but I don't want like that I need the grid view like fallows .In the above set Block nos will different from one row to another If remaining all records are same then block no will be in single row by separating the cama(,) like fallows

```
ActualMachineId BlockScheduleVersionId  ActualStartDate ActivityId  BlockScheduleActivityId BLOCKNO MachineName ActivityName
UT13-PM-4   UT2-BSV-14  13/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-2   2284,6396       
UT13-PM-5   UT2-BSV-5   12/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-4   1239,2277       
UT13-PM-4   UT2-BSV-8   08/06/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-6   1239    
UT13-PM-3   UT2-BSV-9   21/08/2014  UT13-ACT-11 UT2-BSA-8   2283
```

Please Help me the suggestions.Is it possible to do by creating the dynamic data table based on the data set.If Yes How can go through that

This is the way I have tried in this  for checking the previous values I have declared 3 hidden labels.

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            string strBlockNos = lblBlockNos.Text;
            Label lblActualMachineId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblActualMachineId");
            Label lblActivityId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblActivityId");
            Label lblActualStartDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblActualStartDate");
            Label lblBlocks = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblBlocks");
            if (lblActualMachineId.Text == lblMachineId.Text)
            {

                if (lblActivityId.Text == lblActivityhidden.Text)
                {

                    if (lblActualStartDate.Text == lblStartDate.Text)
                    {

                        strBlockNos += lblBlocks.Text + ",";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMachineId.Text = lblActualMachineId.Text;
                        lblActivityhidden.Text = lblActivityId.Text;
                        lblStartDate.Text = lblActualStartDate.Text;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMachineId.Text = lblActualMachineId.Text;
                    lblActivityhidden.Text = lblActivityId.Text;
                    lblStartDate.Text = lblActualStartDate.Text;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMachineId.Text = lblActualMachineId.Text;
                lblActivityhidden.Text = lblActivityId.Text;
                lblStartDate.Text = lblActualStartDate.Text;

                flag = true;
            }
            if (flag == false)
            {
                e.Row.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Here I need to update the previous row
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: by using row data bound. In that I am unable to update the records of the previous row.

Comment: Post your attempt in your question please.

Comment: can u please check once

Comment: Unless am missing something, My suggestion is to create new datatable or model class, group the data and create the expected result. Then bind the grid with the data.

Comment: I'm too lazy to type an answer for you now, but here is how you can do it. Use Linq group by to group by block no and use string.join to join multiple repeating block nos into a single comma separated values and then bind the resultant list to the gridview.